# How to reduce run time of shell script?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, optimization, large-files

I have written a simple code that takes data from a text file( which has space-separated columns and 1.5 million rows) gives the output file with the specified column. But this code takes more than an hr to execute.  Can anyone help me out to optimize runtime

```sh
a=0

cat 1c_input.txt/$1 | while read p  
do

    IFS=" "
    for i in $p
    do
        a=`expr $a + 1`
        if [ $a -eq $2 ]
        then
            echo "$i"
        fi
    done
    a=0
done >> ./1.c.$2.column.freq
```

some lines of sample input:

```
1 ib Jim 34
1 cr JoHn 24
1 ut MaRY 46
2 ti Jim 41
2 ye john 6
2 wf JoHn 22
3 ye jOE 42
3 hx jiM 21
```

some lines of sample output if the second argument entered is 3:

```
Jim
JoHn
MaRY
Jim
john
JoHn
jOE
jiM
```

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve via the script?

Comment: 1 ib Jim 34
1 cr JoHn 24
1 ut MaRY 46
2 ti Jim 41             this is 4 lines sample input and in output I want names only

Comment: `bash: [: 1: unary operator expected` - What ts it supposed to do?

Comment: Please clarify if the goal is to 1) optimize the inefficient code, using only shell commands; or 2) to replace all the code with some other util that does everything faster.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to print just 1 column, then do something like

```
#! /bin/bash
awk -v c="$2" '{print $c}' 1c_input.txt/$1 >> ./1.c.$2.column.freq
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you just want something faster, use a utility like `cut`.  So to
   extract the third field from a single space delimited file *bigfile*
   do:

   ```
   cut -d ' ' -f 3 bigfile
   ```
2. To optimize the shell code in the question, using only builtin shell
   commands, do something like:

   ```
   while read a b c d; echo "$c"; done < bigfile
   ```

   ...if the field to be printed is a command line parameter, there are
   several shell command methods, but they're all based on that line.